# Looking for Proof of the Order of a quandle cohomology group for an n-fold dihedral

Tags: homology-cohomology, dihedral-groups

Does anyone know where the proof that states that the order of a quandle cohomology group for an n-fold dihedral quandle is n is located? I have been told it can be found in one of Niebrzydowski-Przytycki's or Mochizuki's articles but I have yet to find the specific proof.